# How do I find the actual data type of the Element values of a Java DOM element? As of now everything considered as String

Tags: java, xml, dom, types

I have a custom user-defined section within my standard XML. Something like this:

```
<rail:JourneyDate>2014-12-12</rail:JourneyDate>
<rail:Name>Rajadhani</rail:Name>
<rail:AxelCount>12</rail:AxelCount>
<rail:VehicleCount>true</rail:VehicleCount>
<rail:PassangerCount>20.5</rail:PassangerCount>
```

This part of the XML is completely user-defined and can be anything. I am reading it using JAXB and everything is working fine.

The problem is that all the values in the `Dom Element` are considered as `String` but as we can see in the above XML the values can be different data types such as `Date`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Boolean`, `String` etc.

However when I read the value of each element using `element.getTextContent()` then this function always returns `String`. Is there a way to find the actual data type of each `Element` rather than the `String` every time?

Comment: If there is no XSD schema defined for these fields, there is no way JAXB can guess what type they really are (String is the standard guess since everything can be a string). Either you define a schema (and so JAXB will be able to parse them accordingly), or you have to get them as string and parse them on your own following some logic.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thanks for the response. Even I was planning to write my own custom class to find the data type for these elements. In XSD they would be part of `any` type as they are completely user-defined so the confusion has arisen. If there is any other approach please let me know otherwise I will write my own custom class for this case.

Comment: I think you can define your own XmlAdapter and annotate your custom XML field with it. For marshalling and unmarshalling you will be called by JAXB on this class, so you should be able somehow to control the flow. However, you'll still have to do your type check and parsing on your own.

Comment: There are (potentially) schema-aware object models, like XDM for schema-aware XPath 2, XSLT 2 or XQuery 1 and later. So in conjunction with a schema-aware XPath or XSLT/XQuery processor like Saxon EE you can build a tree and navigate and select typed node values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the class to determine the type:

```
public class ExtensionsDatatypeFinder {

    private ExtensionsDatatypeFinder() {}

    //Method to check the datatype for user extension, ILMD, Error extensions
    public static Object dataTypeFinder(String textContent) {

        if (textContent.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || textContent.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            //Check if the Element Text content is of Boolean type
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(textContent);
        } else if (NumberUtils.isParsable(textContent)) {
            //Check if the Element Text content is Number type if so determine the Int or Float
            return textContent.contains(".") ? Float.parseFloat(textContent) : Integer.parseInt(textContent);
        } else {
            return textContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Then called it bypassing the required data:

```
//Check for the datatype of the Element
                final Object simpleFieldValue = ExtensionsDatatypeFinder.dataTypeFinder((String) extension.getValue());

                //Based on the type of Element value write the value into the JSON accordingly
                if (simpleFieldValue instanceof Boolean) {
                    gen.writeBooleanField(extension.getKey(), (Boolean) simpleFieldValue);
                } else if (simpleFieldValue instanceof Integer) {
                    gen.writeNumberField(extension.getKey(), (Integer) simpleFieldValue);
                } else if (simpleFieldValue instanceof Float) {
                    gen.writeNumberField(extension.getKey(), (Float) simpleFieldValue);
                } else {
                    //If instance is String directly add it to the JSON
                    gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) extension.getValue());
                }
```